# UILabel doesn't break line

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel that is supposed to be a multiple lined label, but it isn't. Here's how I did it

```
[self.lblMessage setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[self.lblMessage setCenter:self.view.center];
self.lblMessage.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
_lblMessage.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
_lblMessage.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.view addSubview:self.lblMessage];
```

Comment: are you using autolayout?What are constraints of your label?

Answer (score 0):

[image]your are seting

with auto layout see this pic

here i set height Relation greater than or equal 0 . and i fix the width and remember set the number of line = 0.

Comment: Same result. Even I set numberOfLines to any number

Comment: you can use auto layout . can i give you example of it.

Comment: Ok go ahead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. My UILabel height is too short that's why it doesn't display the other lines. Thanks!